# References in supplemental material - include in main reference section?

Tags: citations, supporting-information

I have some supplemental material that condenses results from a couple of studies in a table (Supplemental Table 1). In the manuscript I refer to my supplemental table. My question is: where should I include the references from Supplemental Table 1? I cannot include them in the main manuscript (right?) as I do not cite these studies in the text and any journal would just list them as references that have not been cited before. I would tend to just list them right under Supplemental Table 1. Is there any correct practise?

Comment: Which journal is it?

Answer (score 2):

It's common practice, however, these might differ between journals.

Likely, when you include them in the main references, they will be flagged as not being mentioned in the manuscript and removed. Unless otherwise instructed in the author guidelines of your journal of choice, simply add them to the supplementary material and see what happens.

Comment: Then again, if not being cited in the manuscript they might not be indexed by databases.